# Zombies At The Fence - filming head injuries to walkers

Tags: effects, the-walking-dead

When zombies (or walkers or however you refer to them) are in an easily kill-able location, such as the fence at the prison, there are many times where spears or swords or other lengthy objects are thrust into and through a zombie's head.  You can see the actor push it deep into the head, you can see the pointy end emerge from the back, and you can also pretty clearly (IMO) see the CGI gore fly out of the back.

I get the gore.  It's pretty obvious.  But, how are the actors thrusting these lengthy objects into the actors portraying zombies?  Is it all hidden by camera angles?  I can't see the spears/swords being CGI, that'd be too tricky.

Comment: Most of the fence zombies are latex props, not actually people. I'll try to find some interviews where they talk about this, and post it as an answer.

Comment: Also, I think you'll find that the spears **are** often digital, too. AMC actually has a great collection of Behind the scenes footage on their YouTube channel.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIVWjKoPt1w Here's a segment on how they lop off heads.

Comment: @BenPlont - I didn't even know this stuff existed, and now I'm hooked!  There's one scene where you can see Michonne stick the sword towards the side of the head, so it definitely looks in part to be somewhat manipulated by the camera angle.

Comment: Yeah, they use a lot of different tricks. camera angles, props, blue screen...

Comment: @BenPlont - Can you put your link in an answer so I can give you points for it?  The link, which led me to other links by A&E, really proved to be informative.

Comment: I added an answer. I will try to expand it when i get more time.

Comment: There are three effects they use: live action with fake props (half sword, rubber knives), animatronic or fake zombies (latex head full of fake blood), and CGI. Check out the extras on the discs (Netflix it) for the gory details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to expand this answer a little more tomorrow..

Most of the fence zombies are latex props, not actually people. I'll try to find some interviews where they talk about this.

Here's a [segment](http://youtube.com/watch?v=GIVWjKoPt1w) on how they lop off heads.